# Base64 encoding of imap body not working

Tags: php, encoding, base64, imap

I have looked all over the place for the past couple of days and still cant find the answer. I have an imap php app that fetches emails from my outlook account, all works perfect and the messages are displayed nice but im having an issue with a couple of emails, bodytype returns as base64 but it doesnt encode properly (only on a couple, all other base64 get nicely decoded). but this one before decoding is...

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIf IiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7Pj4+JS5ESUM8SDc9Pjv/wAALCAB4AHgBAREA/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEB AQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1Fh ByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZ WmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXG x8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oACAEBAAA/APZqKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK/9k=
```

and after decoding its even more gibberish that it stared off with instead of any meaningful text. What is this and how do i decode it properly ?? had a look at online decoders and all say its invalid

> heres an image of what the email looks like in outlook

[image]

Comment: Can You Post Your COde

Comment: Stating the obvious (I hope) but too many smart people are fooled by these things: THIS IMAGE IS A PHISHING MESSAGE. I have seen this with Dropbox, PayPal and other sites. Basically the fake message is generic in content and relates to a common system so there is a good chance the recipient has such an account. But instead of the message being text, which spam filters are good at catching - or at least flagging based on text URL <> actual link - this is entirely an image, so there is no simple text to filter. BEWARE! And never click on such images (once you have them properly decoded).

Comment: FYI, this is not meant as a bad comment on the OP in any way, as he is just trying to decode a message he received - the same technical issue being asked could occur just as easily with any message that consists entirely of a single image. Just a big warning to anyone - including the OP - that receives such messages to beware of phishing attacks.

Comment: thanks manassehkatz, thats not a bad comment at all, i have a project at uni which is anti phishing app but for this purpose i need it to decode the message and analyse the contents, strings in particular, this is an image i relised now but that throws me onto another issue now, my fetchbody is only fetching the little image in the body instead of the entire message which does have text in it, any clues on how to fix that so it fetches the entire message for my analysis

Comment: Too many different varieties of messages. I have done enough to know that it is nearly always possible to decode the messages with PHP, but I have also done enough to know that every time I think I have it all figured out there is a new variation - another non-standard "standard" email format.

Answer (score 0):

> Demo:: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/876m-khae
>
> Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php
>
> View Online Tools Decode Here: https://www.base64decode.org/

```
<?php

$base64_string ="/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIf IiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7Pj4+JS5ESUM8SDc9Pjv/wAALCAB4AHgBAREA/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEB AQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1Fh ByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZ WmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXG x8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oACAEBAAA/APZqKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK/9k=
";

$decode_data = base64_decode($base64_string);

$image_create = imagecreatefromstring($decode_data);
if ($image_create !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($image_create);
    imagedestroy($image_create);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
?>
```

> **NOTE:: You Can Also Use the `base64ToImage` funtion to decode this**

**Example:**

```
<?php

function base64ToImage($base64_string, $output_file) {

     $file = fopen($output_file, "wb");
 
     $data = explode(',', $base64_string);
 
     fwrite($file, base64_decode($data[1]));
     fclose($file);
 
     return $output_file;
}


?>
```

Comment: this is perfect considering what you had to work with its a spot on answer, but thanks to you i just realised another problem im having in this case, my fetchbody is only fetching this little square "image" instead of the entire body which has text in it too, any idea on how to fix that ? many thanks